# XML Parsing through LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, linq

I am doing my web service project using WCF. The problem is that I have an XML file which is like this:

```
<Cars>
    <Make Name="Honda">
        <Model Name="Accord" Year="2013">
            <Price>22480</Price>
        </Model>
        <Model Name="Civic" Year="2013">
            <Price>17965</Price>
        </Model>
        <Model Name="Crosstour" Year="2013">
            <Price>27230</Price>
        </Model>
        <Model Name="CR-V" Year="2013">
            <Price>22795</Price>
        </Model>
    </Make>
</Cars>
```

I want to retrieve the `Price` for the given `Model` where the `Name` attribute is supplied by the user. I am using this Approach:

```
var DBCodes = from Cars in XmlEdit.Descendants("Cars")
    from Make in Cars.Elements("Make")
    from Made in Make.Elements("Made")
    where Made.Attribute("Name").Value == CarName //Variable for Name
    select Make;

foreach (var Make in DBCodes)
{
    if (Make != null)
        PriceOfCar = Make.Element("Price").Value.ToString();
    else
        break;
}
```

But its not working.  Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: isn't it `from Model in Make.Elements("Model")` ?

Comment: Where is `Made` element? Do you have only `Model` name, or you should also search for `Make` name? Do you have several `Make` elements in your xml? What if you have several `Civic` models with different years?

Comment: @vlad Lol. I have been working for so long that my mind Choked. :D Thanks a Lot. I forgot my own schema! Things solved just by making it Model.

Answer (score 3):

```
var cars = 
    XDocument.Load("a.xml")
        .Descendants("Make")
        .Select(make => new
        {
            Name = make.Attribute("Name").Value,
            Models = make.Descendants("Model")
                         .Select(model => new{
                             Name = (string)model.Attribute("Name"),
                             Year = (int)model.Attribute("Year"),
                             Price = (int)model.Element("Price")
                         })
                         .ToList()
        })
        .ToList();



string userInput="Civic";
var price = cars.SelectMany(c => c.Models).First(m => m.Name == userInput).Price;
```

---

You can even get the price directly from xml without converting it into an temporary structure

```
string userInput="Civic";
var price = (int)XDocument.Load("a.xml")
            .Descendants("Model")
            .First(m => (string)m.Attribute("Name") == userInput)
            .Element("Price");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone for helping. The approach is correct. There was only spelling mistake.